# Dictionary and List

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I want to use the dictionary in c# combined with a list like this

```
Dictionary<int, List<int>> Dir = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
```

but I am having trouble with the syntax for adding the keys and values. I thought if I just did something like

```
Dir.Add(integer1, integer2);
```

it would add integer1 was the key, and integer2 as the value. Then if I wanted to add to the integer1 key I would do

```
Dir.Add[interger1].Add(interger3);
```

I had one more question, I had a foreach loop like this to display the keys

```
 foreach (KeyValuePair<int, List<int>> k in labelsList)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(k.Key + " "+ k.Value);
 }
```

it displays the keys I expected up to 7, but it doesn't display the value's I wanted it to show, it just displays

1 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]

2 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]

3 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]

4 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]

5 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]

6 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]

7 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]

I have any idea to use a nested foreach like

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, List<int>> k in labelsList)
{
     foreach (KeyValuePair<int, List<int>> k in labelsList)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(k.Key + " " + k.Value);
     }
}
```

but I am unsure of what to put inside the nested foreach to iterate through the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `Dir.Add()`, you need to provide a *reference* to a `List<int>` *object*. Providing an `int` itself is not right. So you need something like this:

```
Dir.Add(integer1, new List<int>());
```

Then you can update that entry like this:

```
Dir[integer1].Add(integer2);
Dir[integer1].Add(integer3);
```

Alternatively, you can use the collection initializer syntax:

```
Dir.Add(integer1, new List<int> { integer2, integer3});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the collection into the dictionary before you can start adding values to it. Here is a solution which make one lookup (compared to two if `ContainsKey` is used). It also adds the list if it's missing.

```
public class YourClass
{
    private Dictionary<int, List<int>> _dictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();

    public void AddItem(int key, int value)
    {
        List<int> values;
        if (!_dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out values))
        {
            values = new List<int>();
            _dictionary.Add(key, values);
        }

        values.Add(value);
    }

    public IEnumerable<int> GetValues(int key)
    {
        List<int> values;
        if (!_dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out values))
        {
            return new int[0];
        }

        return values;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `if` condition should be `if(!_dictionary.TryGetValue(...))` :)

Comment: @Adam Houldsworth: Thanks for fixing =) I also added a GetValues method.

Answer (score 0):

First, create an entry for your key `integer1`, unless you have already done so:

```
Dir.Add(integer1, new List<int>());
```

Then, find the right dictionary entry, then add to its value (in this case, your list):

```
Dir[integer1].Add(integer2);
```

You will find more entire code snippets in the other answers, if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Will throw `NullReferenceException` when key does not exists in the dictionary.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek It will throw a `KeyNotFoundException` if the key isn't in the dictionary.

Comment: He asked for the *syntax*.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `List<int>` as value. It'll work like this:

```
if (!Dir.ContainsKey(integer1)) {
  Dir.Add(integer1, new List<int>());
}

var list = Dir[integer1];
list.Add(integer2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add an item, simply use this code

(whereas `dic` is your `Dictionary<Int32, List<Int32>>`)

```
if (dic.ContainsKey(yourKey))
{
   dic[yourKey].Add(yourInt);
} else {
   dic[yourKey] = new List<int> { yourInt };
}
```